To which value does converge the objective: $target = (r + \gamma Q(s',*)) / 2$
Conditions:

Assume you have a DRL SAC implementation.
You train it as usual from Replay Buffer with uniform sampling with replacement.

Assume you change the target of the Q-network from:
$$T = r + \gamma Q(s',*) $$
To:
$$T^* = \frac{r + \gamma Q(s',*)}{2} $$
Then:

To which values will now converge the Q-values? I mean, will it converge to an average reward as in average reward RL? Diverges?

I have done some tests and I have convergence to some value, but I don't know to which value it is converging to.

Is there a simple proof that the objective: $T^*$ does not converge to the average reward?



"to which value it will converge"... what does that mean??

In the DRL replay buffer training scenario, T converges to the expected cumulative sum of rewards (r), to which value converges T*?

RL aims at finding a policy $\pi$ that maximizes $G = \mathbb{E_\pi}[\sum \gamma^i r_i]$
Note how this is an expectation, so it's scale (positive) and shift invariant... indeed, given a reward function $R(s,a,s')$, a second function $R(s,a,s')' = R(s,a,s')+c$ would lead to the same policy $\pi$, as per positive scalings
In other words, you would get (in the optimal regime) the same policy

Thanks, but forget about the policy, it is in the Q-values estimate in which I am interested in

@JoseAntonioMartinH they will be half

thanks @alberto yes, I've developed it mathematically and it converges to Q/2

@JoseAntonioMartinH you're welcome
